Acts 13:43 and the grace of God

43 Now when the meeting of the synagogue had broken up, many of the
Jews and the God-fearing proselytes followed Paul and Barnabas, who
were speaking to them and urging them to continue in the grace of God.
(Acts 13:43, NASB 2020)

When Luke says that Paul and Barnabas urged those Jews and God-fearing proselytes to continue in the grace of God, should we conclude that those had converted to Christianity, or not just yet?

Based on what Paul states is the requirement for "conversion", I would say yes, these individuals have believed the gospel of God's grace and are now "Christians":
Acts 16:29-31

Then he called for a light, and sprang in, and came trembling, and fell down before Paul and Silas,
30 And brought them out, and said, Sirs, what must I do to be saved?
31 And they said, Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ, and thou shalt be saved, and thy house.

Ephesians 2:8-9

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Romans 3:21-26

But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being witnessed by the law and the prophets;
22 Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that believe: for there is no difference:
23 For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God;
24 Being justified freely by his grace through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus:
25 Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;
26 To declare, I say, at this time his righteousness: that he might be just, and the justifier of him which believeth in Jesus.

Romans 4:3-5

For what saith the scripture? Abraham believed God, and it was counted unto him for righteousness.
4 Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt.
5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness.

1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:


This question is explicitly answered in Titus 2:11 -

For the grace of God has appeared, bringing salvation to all men

The phrase "grace of God" is almost a technical phrase signifying the enabling power of God for salvation by grace as shown many times in the NT -

Acts 11:23 - I thank my God always concerning you for the grace of God having been given you [converts] in Christ Jesus
Acts 14:26 - And from there they sailed to Antioch, from where they had been committed to the grace of God for the work that they had fulfilled.
Rom 5:15 - But the gift is not like the trespass. For if the many died [ie, all] by the trespass of the one man, how much more did the grace of God and the gift that came by the grace of the one man, Jesus Christ, abound to the many [ie, all]!
1 Cor 1:4 - I thank my God always concerning you [converts to Christ] for the grace of God having been given you in Christ Jesus,
1 Cor 15:10 - But by the grace of God I am what I am, and His grace to me was not in vain. No, I worked harder than all of them—yet not I, but the grace of God that was with me.
2 Cor 8:1 - Now we make known to you, brothers, the grace of God having been bestowed among the churches of Macedonia
Eph 3:2 - Surely you have heard of the administration of the grace of God, having been given to me toward you,
Eph 3:7 - I became a servant of this gospel by the gift of the grace of God, given me through the working of His power.
Heb 2:9 - But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels, because of the suffering of death, having been crowned with glory and with honor, so that by the grace of God He might taste death for everyone.
etc.

That is, anyone who has and "continues in the grace of God" (Acts 13:43) is saved.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
